# Is Apple ID still considered as linked with my MacBook if I totally reinstall my Mackbook but use another Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id

For example, suppose I don't unlink my Mackbook in Apple ID, but I totally reinstall my MacBook and start using with another Apple ID. My question is, is my Apple ID considered as linked with that MacBook? Or in other words, does Apple ID link to the hardware serial Id?

Answer (score 1):

As far as the Mac is concerned, yes. So that purchased software, iCloud syncing, etc. will no longer be associated (or available to) you on that Mac under that old AppleID.

But you will still need to log into that particular iCloud account and go to settings and then My Devices and remove that device there as well.

Comment: I think your first sentence contradicts the second? Did you mean "no" rather than "yes"?

Comment: Nope that is correct, the second paragraph removes the Mac from Apple's servers. When you sign in with another AppleID it will automatically add it to the new account.

Comment: Second *sentence*, not paragraph. If that's what you meant to write, I'm legitimately really confused. You're saying the Apple ID is still linked to the mac, *but* that purchased software and iCloud syncing won't be linked to the Mac? How can those things both be true? You should clarify.

Comment: ...looking over one more time alongside your comment... I understand what you're saying now. But you should make more clear